# function Add (into a list) do something strange

Tags: java, jsf

I have a problem that can look dumb but it s been 3 hours that im stuck. When I add an element in my arrayList I do not add what i am supposed to.

Basically on the Sysout you can see the value which I am supposed to have and on the value from B you can see that I only add the last value...

```
private List<ContextSchemeValue> ConvertCodeListIntoContextSchemeValue (List<CodeListValue> A){
   ContextSchemeValue C= new ContextSchemeValue();
   List<ContextSchemeValue> B = new ArrayList<>();

   for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i=i+1) {
         C.setContextScheme(contextScheme);
         C.setMeaning(A.get(i).getName());
         C.setValue(A.get(i).getValue());

         System.out.println("   C"+i+" = "+C);
         B.add(C);
     }
    System.out.println("            B =" + B);
    return B;
}
```

C0 = ContextSchemeValue{ctxSchemeValueId=0, guid='null', value='fefe', meaning='fefe', contextScheme=ContextScheme{ctxSchemeId=0, guid='null', schemeId='null', schemeName='null', description='null', schemeAgencyId='2', schemeVersionId='99999', contextCategory=null, createdBy=0, lastUpdatedBy=0, creationTimestamp=null, lastUpdateTimestamp=null}}

C1 = ContextSchemeValue{ctxSchemeValueId=0, guid='null', value='efefewfeasf', meaning='efewfw', contextScheme=ContextScheme{ctxSchemeId=0, guid='null', schemeId='null', schemeName='null', description='null', schemeAgencyId='2', schemeVersionId='99999', contextCategory=null, createdBy=0, lastUpdatedBy=0, creationTimestamp=null, lastUpdateTimestamp=null}}

C2 = ContextSchemeValue{ctxSchemeValueId=0, guid='null', value='fef', meaning='fwefefef', contextScheme=ContextScheme{ctxSchemeId=0, guid='null', schemeId='null', schemeName='null', description='null', schemeAgencyId='2', schemeVersionId='99999', contextCategory=null, createdBy=0, lastUpdatedBy=0, creationTimestamp=null, lastUpdateTimestamp=null}}

B =[ContextSchemeValue{ctxSchemeValueId=0, guid='null', value='fef', meaning='fwefefef', contextScheme=ContextScheme{ctxSchemeId=0, guid='null', schemeId='null', schemeName='null', description='null', schemeAgencyId='2', schemeVersionId='99999', contextCategory=null, createdBy=0, lastUpdatedBy=0, creationTimestamp=null, lastUpdateTimestamp=null}},

ContextSchemeValue{ctxSchemeValueId=0, guid='null', value='fef', meaning='fwefefef', contextScheme=ContextScheme{ctxSchemeId=0, guid='null', schemeId='null', schemeName='null', description='null', schemeAgencyId='2', schemeVersionId='99999', contextCategory=null, createdBy=0, lastUpdatedBy=0, creationTimestamp=null, lastUpdateTimestamp=null}},

ContextSchemeValue{ctxSchemeValueId=0, guid='null', value='fef', meaning='fwefefef', contextScheme=ContextScheme{ctxSchemeId=0, guid='null', schemeId='null', schemeName='null', description='null', schemeAgencyId='2', schemeVersionId='99999', contextCategory=null, createdBy=0, lastUpdatedBy=0, creationTimestamp=null, lastUpdateTimestamp=null}}]

I really do not understand why the add function keep adding the last value and not the other one, I printed the value on each i, well thanks for help !

Comment: You were probably downvoted because it's not super clear what the question is. What output are you expecting?

Comment: I edited my post, thx for telling me it was not clear, i m stuck on this problem for hours so I did not see that it was not really clear ;)

Comment: And maybe because of the (lack of)  fpr,atting

Comment: Please don't deface your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're adding the same `C` object into the list three times, then changing the same object three times in the loop. The list doesn't contain three different objects, it contains three references to *the same object*.

When you write:

```
C.setValue(A.get(i).getValue())
```

You're changing the value of `C`, not creating a new `C`. If you already have references to `C` in the list, they'll be changed too.

I'm not familiar with `ContextSchemeValue`s, but you'll need to create new ones each time instead of reusing the same object three times, then adding the three references to the same object into the list.

Comment: Yeah it take sense... I defined my object out of the loop so oc it will change its value, sorry for asking such a dumb question. Thx a lot !!!!!